# Is it possible to generate OpenAPI docs for specific user roles?

Tags: symfony, openapi, api-platform.com

I have build an API using API Platform with the auto-generated OpenAPI docs (SwaggerUI).

I also have endpoints secured for specific user roles (also some properties are secured using ApiResource security.

Now I want to generate OpenAPI docs **only** for the allowed endpoints and properties based on that role.

Is that even possible? And if so: how?